# Pythonic way to find discrete autocorrelation function

Tags: python, correlation

I want to evaluate the auto-correlation function,
[image]
in the discretized version when the integral can be replaced by
[image]

I have written the following code to do to calculate the summation over n, but cannot understand how to proceed further.

```
from pylab import* 
from numpy import*

jx=random.random(100000)

Mt=len(jx)

def Hcacf(n):       
    Sum=0.0
    coeff1=0
    while coeff1 < (Mt-n) :
        Sum = Sum + jx[coeff1]*jx[coeff1+n]
        coeff1=coeff1+1
    avg = Sum*1.0 / (Mt-n)
    return avg

autocorrelation=[]
for n in linspace(0, Mt-1, num=Mt, endpoint=False):
    ac=Hcacf(n+1)
    autocorrelation.append(ac)

lag=linspace(0,Mt-1,Mt)
plot(lag,autocorrelation,marker='o')
show()
```

But it takes a very long time to run. Can someone suggest me a better way to use pythonic tools to do the same process faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044491/statistical-scaling-of-autocorrelation-using-numpy-fft) should answer your question. In essence, quoting the answer in the link you can define autocorrelate function using `np.correlate` as follows

```
import numpy as np
def AutoCorrelation(x):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    y = x-x.mean()
    result = np.correlate(y, y, mode='full')
    result = result[len(result)//2:]
    result /= result[0]
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot you just use `numpy.correlate` on the the function and do the multiplication with the factor just in the end? How do you treat the infinite support? Don't you need some condition of convergence (just guessing...)?

Comment: I dont know how to implement that in this case. Can you tell me about it in more details